# Restore data file from sql server backup file without restoring the log file

Tags: sql-server

I have a client who needs support with SQL Server. The client has provided a backup of the database. Upon trying to restore the database for testing, I realized that the data file is 100MB while the log file is 250GB which makes it impossible to restore on my development computer.

I have seen it is possible to create SQL virtual databases using [idera SQL virtual database](http://www.idera.com/SQL-Toolbox/) and [Redgate SQL Virtual Restore](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/) but I haven't done any testing on these tools.

Is is possible to extract or restore the data file (mdf) alone without the log file (ldf)?

Comment: For all intents and purposes: no. The data file (`.mdf`) and transaction log file (`.ldf`) are a unity that belong together and have to be handled together, at all times

Comment: Why is it impossible to restore to your development computer?

Comment: I'm guessing he doesn't have 250 GB of free space

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is way to only restore one and not both.  Instead of having the client sending you a backup have them send you the .MDF only in a single file.  They may have to detach the database first before they can copy the .MDF file.  Another alternative is to stop the SQL Service temporarily while they copy the file.

You should be able to attach the database with just the MDF file.  If the LDF file does not exist it will create one automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks @DanP  Unfortunately my client has minimal knowledge in technical issues. Seeing I am limited on options, I think I will have to connect remotely, temporarily stop the service and make a copy of the MDF.